# Why did Ethereum design Ethash instead of using an existing memory-hard hash function?

Tags: mining, ethash, architecture

Ethereum uses the [Ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) hash function for proof-of-work. It was designed specifically for this purpose by Vitalik based on previous work by Thaddeus Dryja.

The main rule they teach you in a crypto class is: never roll out your own crypto. Why not take any of the existing memory hard hash functions? From [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) used in Litecoin and its forks to any of the [PHC competition](https://password-hashing.net/) finalists (also, Zcash later chose Equihash, designed by the authors of the PHC winner, for its PoW).

I did not find any academic papers with cryptanalysis of Ethash. [This analysis](https://github.com/LeastAuthority/ethereum-analyses/blob/master/PoW.md) elaborates on why password hashing and PoW are not entirely the same task, but still gives no rationale for designing a new algorithm.

Ethash serves its purpose well for now, but what if a critical vulnerability is found? For a recently developed algorithm without years of cryptanalysis behind it it seems likely compared to more established alternatives.

What was the rationale behind choosing to design a new hash function for Ethereum's PoW?

Comment: This might shed some light: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash-Design-Rationale . I seem to recall reading a blog post by vbuterin, but I can't locate it at the moment.

Comment: I think @lungj's comment answers at least part of what you're asking (and would be worth adding as a partial answer, in my opinion).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though it's only a partial answer, this might shed some light: http://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash-Design-Rationale . I seem to recall reading a blog post by vbuterin, but I can't locate it at the moment.

The main points can be found in that link, and are as follows:

> - IO saturation: The algorithm should consume nearly the entire available memory access bandwidth (this is a strategy toward achieving
>     ASIC resistance, the argument being that commodity RAM, especially in
>     GPUs, is much closer to the theoretical optimum than commodity
>     computing capacity)
> - GPU friendliness: We try to make it as easy as possible to mine with GPUs. Targeting CPUs is almost certainly impossible, as potential
>     specialization gains are too great, and there do exist criticisms of
>     CPU-friendly algorithms that they are vulnerable to botnets, so we
>     target GPUs as a compromise.
> - Light client verifiability: a light client should be able to verify a round of mining in under 0.01 seconds on a desktop in C, and under
>     0.1 seconds in Python or Javascript, with at most 1 MB of memory (but exponentially increasing)
> - Light client slowdown: the process of running the algorithm with a light client should be much slower than the process with a full
>     client, to the point that the light client algorithm is not an
>     economically viable route toward making a mining implementation,
>     including via specialized hardware.
> - Light client fast startup: a light client should be able to become fully operational and able to verify blocks within 40 seconds in
>     Javascript.